# Require approval for all outside collaborators on a specific workflow

Tags: github-actions

On my GitHub repository I have 2 workflows running after pull requests:

1. Test workflow
2. CLA assistant workflow

On my test workflow, I have [Secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) that I wouldn't like to expose to other people. Therefore, for security reasons, I'd like to manually review a pull request before running the tests.

GitHub allows me to configure the [required approval for workflows from public forks](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#configuring-required-approval-for-workflows-from-public-forks). This configuration is per repository and I'd like to configure it per workflow. In other words - the requirement is that the CLA assistant will run on each pull request, but the tests will run only after a maintainer click on the [Approve and run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/approving-workflow-runs-from-public-forks#approving-workflow-runs-on-a-pull-request-from-a-public-fork) button.

Does somebody have an idea how to make the CLA assistant running for each PR, but the tests only after clicking on the Approve button?